Увеличение лимита размера файла при экспорте диалогов из телеграмм
В тг есть функция export chat history но самый большой размер файла 4000мб, как поднять этот порог или обойти ограничение? Может есть софт готовый или библиотеки?
https://telegram.org/blog/export-and-more?setln=tr
